# filtering text in a textview in android

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to remove integers from `TextView` in android. For example let's say we have text like this:

`123Isuru456Ranasinghe`

I want this text to be like this after removing integers

`IsuruRanasinghe`

How do I achieve this in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will Help you.

```
  public static String removeDigits(String text) {
        int length = text.length();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(length);
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            char ch = text.charAt(i);
            if (!Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                buffer.append(ch);
            }
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
```

**Another Simple Option :**

```
// do it in just one line of code
String num = text.replaceAll(”[\\d]“, “”);
```

Return your string with Removing Digits.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (!Character.isDigit(ch))`?

Comment: You may also think of renaming the method to `removeDigits`.

Comment: That function preserves the digits and not the characters, so you should put in a "!" before Character.isDigit(ch) to get characters. - edit: I guess I was a bit too slow :)

Answer (score 3):

This is just pure java. Nothing to do with Android.
Here is the code to do what you want.

```
String str = "123Isuru456Ranasinghe";
String newStr = str.replaceAll("[0-9]", "");
```

After some tests, it seems that the longest solution is the best in the matter of performance !

```
public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException {
    // Building a long string...
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        str.append("123Isuru456Ranasinghe");

    removeNum1(str.toString());
    removeNum2(str.toString());
}

// With a replaceAll => 1743 ms
private static void removeNum1(String _str) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String finalString = _str.replaceAll("[0-9]", "");
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
}

// With StringBuilder and loop => 348 ms
private static void removeNum2(String _str) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();
    char currentChar;
    for (int i = 0; i < _str.length(); ++i) {
        currentChar = _str.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(currentChar)) {
            finalString.append(currentChar);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
}
```

Using a loop is much faster.
But in your case, it is a bit useless :p

Now you have to choose between "slow" and short to write and very fast but a bit more complicated. All depend of what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();
char currentChar;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
    currentChar = str.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isLetter(currentChar)) {
        ans.append(currentChar);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is very good if you want to optimize the performance of your application during the processing of a long string.